# Como restringir permissões do GitHub em Windows? (Para pedir a senha toda vez)

Tags: git, github

Olá,

**Preciso que em todo commit a senha senha solicitada.** Atualmente a senha está salva e não preciso digitá-la. 
Creio que eu tenha salvo essa senha de alguma forma (na verdade eu nem sabia o que estava fazendo quando configurei...).

Obs.: Estou utilizando o Windows (no meu ubuntu está tudo ok).

Comment: A senha só é pedida em `PULL` e `PUSH`, caso não tenha cadastrado os hash das chaves no site do git hub. Acredito que, se for isso, é só não cadastrar a chave.

Comment: Na verdade ele não pede senha pra nada (nem no pull ou push).            Não possuo nenhuma chave no github, por esse motivo no meu Ubuntu ele sempre pede usuário e senha.                                           Me lembro que no windows, quando fiz o primeiro push, uma janela foi aberta onde coloquei usuário e senha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se foi perguntado por usuário e senha da primeira vez, certamente você está usando o repositório com HTTPS.

A primeira coisa é descobrir como você está armazenando esta senha. Digite o comando:

```
git config --system --list
```

Veja o que diz na linha `credential.helper`. Se o valor for **manager**:

```
credential.helper=manager
```

O usuário e senha foram armazenados nas credenciais do Windows. Para remover de lá, vá em:

```
Control Panel → User Accounts → Credential Manager → Manage Windows Credentials
```

Localize a credencial https://github.com e apague-a.

Agora, se o valor for **store**:

```
credential.helper=store
```

Você está usando o próprio gerenciador de usuário e senha do Git. Para remover de lá, use o comando:

```
git config --global --unset credential.helper
```

Após isto, o próximo `pull`/`push` irá pedir o usuário e senha novamente.